# Clickable Qlabel: Binding multiple labels to a single function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have all this labels declared in a initUi
They are constructed like that:

```
        ligne_1_left_cord = 300
        self.label_ligne_1_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        pic_signe_tab =QPixmap('img/tab.png')
        self.label_ligne_1_1.setPixmap(pic_signe_tab)
        self.label_ligne_1_1.move(ligne_1_left_cord,300)
        self.label_ligne_1_1.mousePressEvent = self.label_click

        self.label_ligne_1_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label_ligne_1_2.setPixmap(pic_signe_tab)
        self.label_ligne_1_2.move( ligne_1_left_cord +85,300)
```

When I click label_ligne_1_1 the function label_click does this:

```
def label_click(self,event):
        signe_pixmap = QPixmap('img/tabx.png')
        self.label_ligne_1_1.setPixmap(signe_pixmap)
```

[image]

Is there anyway I could pass a variable when I'm calling label_click in order to bind it to all labels and use the same function?
Something like this?:

```
def label_click(name_of_the_lable):
    name_of_the_lable.setPixmap(x)
```

Meaning of course that no matter on what square you click, the pixmap will change and an X will appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding functions in that way is not suggested, especially for what are considered protected functions in Qt, which is the case of any `*Event()` function of QObjects and QWidgets.

Also, in your case you're just overwriting the method with the same signature, which would never allow you to get the source of the function call.
A possible solution would be to use a lambda with the source as a keyword argument:

```
self.label_ligne_1_1.mousePressEvent = lambda ev, label=self.label_ligne_1_1: self.label_click(label)
```

But I wouldn't suggest you to do that.
A better approach, instead, would be to install an [event filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) on each label, and then set the pixmap each time a mouse press event is captured:

```
class Squares(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        for row in range(4):
            for col in range(4):
                square = QtWidgets.QLabel()
                square.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('tab.png'))
                layout.addWidget(square, row, col)
                setattr(self, 'label_ligne_{}_{}'.format(row + 1, col + 1), square)
                square.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            source.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('tabx.png'))
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

Comment: I didn't create a layout as you did but I managed by installing an event filter as you suggested to each of my labels by doing this  self.label_ligne_1_2.installEventFilter(self). Thank you!

Comment: I used the layout for simplicity, but I'd suggest you to use it anyway, because different systems might display the image contents differently (depends on a moltitude of factors, but it's mainly due to the DPI of the screen), resulting in unexpected displaying of images and, possibly overlapping or undersizing.

Comment: I would like to, my code is already too repetitive and crating each label individually  takes a lot of space. But I cant archive the exact result as in my picture. If I'm using your layout they are all across the window and spaced. I need them in one specific place of the windows bcs there are other elements around those columns of labels. Such as labels and text. Is there anyway I could archive the same result I have with something similar as your code?

Comment: I try (and suggest) to avoid any fixed positioning of objects as much as possible. It usually requires some thinking about the "right" layout approach to use (which could lead to using nested layouts), but it usually is the best solution. Anyway, I cannot help you with that in the comments; try to get it with some tests, and if you still cannot achieve the required results, create a new question.